# Help with proof that a binomial random graph with m edges is equally likely to be any uniform random graph with m edges

Tags: random-graphs

I'm currently working through *Introduction to Random Graphs* by Frieze & Karonski, and I'm struggling with some of the notation (and quite possibly some background concepts) in a lemma.

Please note that I'm quite the newcomer to mathematics.  I kindly ask you to err on the side of over-explaining, as I have very little background in the field.  (I'm working on it!)

### Context

The book begins by presenting two models of random graphs.

The first is called *uniform random graph*, and it models random graphs as the set of all graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.  It is denoted by $\mathbb G{_n}{_,}{_m} = ([n], E{_n}{_,}{_m})$.  It's probability is assigned by: $$\mathbb P(G) = \binom{\binom n 2}{m}^{{^-}{^1}}$$

The second is called *binomial random graph*, and it models random graphs as a set of $n$ vertices with a probability $p$ of an edge existing for each vertex pair.  It is denoted by $\mathbb G{_n}{_,}{_p} = ([n], E{_n}{_,}{_p})$.  It's probability is assigned by:  $$\mathbb P(G) = p^m(1-p)^{{^\binom n 2}{^-}{^m}}$$

### Question

**Lemma**:  A random graph $G{_n}{_,}{_p}$ given that its number of edges is $m$, is equally likely to be one of the $\binom{\binom n 2}{m}$ graphs that have $m$ edges.

The book offers the following proof, which I'm having trouble understanding:

[image: proof of lemma 1.1]

**Question 1:** What allows us to write the first line of the proof?  It's not obvious to me that

$${\mathbb P}(\mathbb G{_n}{_,}{_p} = G_0 | |E{_n}{_,}{_p}| = m) = \frac{\mathbb {P}(\mathbb G{_n}{_,}{_p} = G_0 , |E{_n}{_,}{_p}| = m)}{\mathbb {P}(| E{_n}{_,}{_p}| = m)}$$.

Is this Bayes theorem in disguise?

**Subquestion:** how do I read the numerator?  Specifically, what does the comma designate?

Comment: The comma denotes "and". This is the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Ah right ok!  The comma is simply $\cap$ ...  I recognize it now. :)